# How to display a ProgressBar on a View while doing some work?

Tags: android, android-listview, progress-bar

I have a view with `EditText`, `Button` and `ListView`.
Button's `onClick()` parses some site (this part works OK), but it takes some time to display the parsed info in `ListView`, so I want to display small `ProgressBar` on the place, where the `ListView` should take place after a while.

So, I add this to my layout (I write important part here):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".86" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight=".14" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar" >

        <ProgressBar 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In source code:

```
progressBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

And everytime I want to show the `ProgressBar`, I do this:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

for disabling:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I work this out?

Comment: *But this doesn't work.* - this isn't very helpful. Care to explain  better what is the problem?

Comment: I can't see any `ProgressBar` displayed. It works just like it worked without adding `ProgressBar` trifles.

Comment: Agree with Luksprog, but I would be willing to guess your parsing is blocking (so the setvisibility codes are not executing until post-parse).  There are a ton of ways to solve this but I would recommend doing a search for progressbar and asynctask (there are other ways to accomplish this as well, but basically you need to kick off a non blocking displayprogressbar method at the same time you do your parsing, then in the displayprogressbar check for completion of parse process before returning).

Comment: I'm guessing that you add that `RelativeLayout` with the `ProgressBar` to your current layout file, which will most likely be incorrect pushing it outside of the visual area making it invisible. But without seeing the full layout file this is just a guess.

Comment: @Luksprog, edited the post. Yes, you're right. Then, what should I do?

Comment: You left out the important part from the layout, how you position those three layouts(the `Linearlayout` and the following two `RelativeLayouts`) in the main `RelativeLayout`(their width/height, positioning rules etc). If this fails have a look at what logray said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to manipulate your `ProgressBar`'s visibility. `ListView` has a feature called "empty view" which is shown only if your `ListView` is empty. Here's what you need to do to use it:

1. If your activity extends `ListActivity`, use
   `android:id="@android:id/list"` for your `ListView` and
   `android:id="@android:id/empty"` for your `ProgressBar`.
2. If you don't extend `ListActivity`, there's a `setEmptyView()`
   method of your `ListView`, which lets you do the same thing.

The above method fits best if you don't need to empty your `ListView` (e.g. data is loaded only once, at the activity startup). If you need to set data after that, it is better to use `ViewSwitcher`, which also has great advantage - it lets you apply transition animation. For details on `ViewSwitcher`, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using an async task like mentioned above.

```
/**
 * this class performs all the work, shows dialog before the work and dismiss it after
 */
 public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

/** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
private ProgressDialog dialog;
/** application context. */
private ListActivity activity;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
    this.dialog.show();
}

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }


    //do whatever with your data
}

protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
   try{    
      //parsing of your website here...

      return true;
   } catch (Exception e)
      Log.e("tag", "error", e);
      return false;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using modal dialogs has one disadvantage - They block the entire window. User might want to continue interacting with the application while loading is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

The `RelativeLayout` with the `ListView` is hiding your `ProgressBar`.Modify the layout like this and see how it goes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".86" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight=".14" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/layout1"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar" >

        <ProgressBar 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small" />

    </RelativeLayout>   


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also have a look [at one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556492/android-progress-dialog-within-listview), for a somewhat similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to nest your `ProgressBar` in another `RelativeLayout`. Just center it in your main layout and put it at last so it remains at the top.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   // the rest  

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, who are interested in the answer.

Main tags are only written.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".86" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight=".14" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#DDE7E7E8"
        android:id="@+id/pBar" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `AsyncTask`:

```
private class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private LinearLayout pBar; 

    private Parsing()
    {
        pBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        parsingHere();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```