# Unable to align circular Progress Bar(centered) on top of Listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, progress-bar

I need to show the progressbar at center while loading the listview using Asynctask. But i was unable to solve it by using the questions in in stack up until now. I think it is due to the parent alignment issue. It is not visible even if its visibility is set as visible in the xml. Here is the xml code im using:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roll_up_board_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/pg_header_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <com.adc.zxyx.global.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/settings_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/COMMENTS"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_loading"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/update_comment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadingEdge="@null"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/update_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/header2"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dwn_arw" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_bg_rounded" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sign_up_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/signup2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/post_comment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_btn"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_up_icon"
                    android:background="@color/grey_bg"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/comment_field_hint1"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" >
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/send_btn_bg"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/SEND"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i check your code its coming int the centre.can you show image  here or little detail about your problem.

Comment: @Chandan Yes, its coming in the center but it is below the listview, so it is not visible at all.

Comment: ...Hope you solve your problem..if not try to take your progress bar in a linear layout and then disable and enable that layout.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709992/how-to-display-a-progressbar-on-a-view-while-doing-some-work). In the selected answer (andranikAzizbekyan) .He worked on the same way to help out.Hope it also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you were asking, but I have a feeling you'll find this solution a bit more attractive than your current one.

Install [Dev Apps Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) on your device.

Skip the "ActionBar-PullToRefresh" example (there are more examples in the pre-4.0 version).

Skip over the other progress bar/progress wheel examples.

Select the "Pull to Refresh" example. And click on "Run Demo" (this one is the pre-4.0 version. It's my favorite one despite the fact that it's deprecated in favor of the new ActionBar-PullToRefresh example).

Its code can be [found here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).